# How to change the search result page

Tags: catalogsearch

When i perform a search in the shop. when the search result page turns up it is still in the default magento theme.

I cannot find an option in the cms to set this page to use the theme that i have downloaden.

Answer (score 2):

In the admin go to System -> Index Management. On that page click Select All, Actions = refresh, then click Update (orange button).

Next, go to System -> Cache Management and flush all caches.

- Flush Magento Cache
- Flush Cache Storage
- Select All, Action = Refresh, Submit
- Flush Catalog Image Cache
- Flush Javascript/CSS Cache

To test if this fixes the issue: Use Chrome - Incongnito mode or Firefox - Private Window, to make sure that you are not getting a cached version of the page, and run a search for a product.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help!
This unfortunately did not help the search page still is in the default magento theme.

I have executed everything u said.

*** edit***
What did the trick was to set a design change
now the theme also is visible on the search result page.